# How to send the data using postman having time type value in it?

Tags: rest, postman

I want to send the JSON data using postman having time type field in it. What should be the format to send time type data?

I tried giving it in string but it doesn't work.

```
{
    "userName" : "bdsfksd",
    "amount" : 456.165,
    "status" : "dsfkndsl" ,
    "time" : "10:50" ,
    "date" : "1997-02-02"
}
```

My class looks like --

```
package com.sm.test.dto;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class PickUp {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int requestId;

    private String userName;
    private double amount;
    private String status;
    private Time time;
    private Date date;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried sending it in milliseconds - Using the `{{$timestamp}}` syntax would create that value.